# Flutter how to retrieve value from button

Tags: flutter

```
  new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("933478476")

          )
```

Here i created one button now i want to store the value of button in string.How to store the values from widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FlatButton` dosen't take any value and would not return either. What you could do is, pass a void callback that triggers your function that takes button click values as arguments.

Example:

```
//Define you function that takes click
void _onClick(String value) {
  //do something
}

// Make you `FlatButton` like this
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () => _onClick('12345678'), // a lambda void callback that calls your click function with value
  child: Text('12345678'),
);
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: No ,the question requires an answer that shows if it is possible to get the text of a label dynamically, same way you can do ```.innerText``` in JavaScript.